# Application is shutting down. Reason: Configuration changed

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, appdomain, application-pool, recycle

> Event code: 1002
>   Event message: Application is shutting down. Reason: Configuration changed.
>   Event time: 11/10/2015 7:22:10 PM
>   Event time (UTC): 11/11/2015 12:22:10 AM
>   Event ID: 17e16b73083c40fea3b3b8416a817f0a
>   Event sequence: 28983
>   Event occurrence: 1
>   Event detail code: 50004

Application information:

> Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-362662626362636
>   Trust level: Full
>   Application Virtual Path: /
>   Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\appname\
>   Machine name: CLNJWEB10

Process information:

> Process ID: 6340
>   Process name: w3wp.exe
>   Account name:

Custom event details:

I want to know what is the cause of this issue. How do I trace what happened?
Can anyone help me to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to highlight the blocks of information by prefixing them with >.  To separate the lines I used two trailing spaces.  Please provide more information on the application.  Did you buy it or did you write it ?  What is it written in ?  And what was it doing when it crashed ?

Comment: Did you find out how?

Comment: still not as the information given is give any idea?